# Create object with different colors on faces

Tags: three.js

Drawing a Tetrahedron, I would like to set one color per face, for example, red, green, blue and orange.

Here is the code :

```js
const divid = document.getElementById("myid");

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  70,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  1,
  1000
);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

divid.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 3;

let triangle = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.TetrahedronBufferGeometry(),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
  );
scene.add(triangle);

let animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  triangle.rotation.x += 0.005;
  triangle.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Can't we pass an array of 4 colors to set on each face ?
Code available here too : https://codepen.io/jeffprod/pen/JjdLdjO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.vertexColors: true` with the material and add `color` attribute to the geometry, setting the same colour to each vertex of a face:

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  70,
  innerWidth / innerHeight,
  1,
  1000
);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 3;

let geom = new THREE.TetrahedronBufferGeometry();
geom.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([
  1, 0, 0, //red
  1, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, //green
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1, //blue
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1,
  1, 0.75, 0.25, //orange (sort of)
  1, 0.75, 0.25,
  1, 0.75, 0.25
], 3));
let triangle = new THREE.Mesh(
  geom,
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: true
  })
);
scene.add(triangle);

let animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  triangle.rotation.x += 0.005;
  triangle.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `THREE.VertexColors` is actually deprecated. `vertexColors` is now just a boolean ;)

Comment: @Mugen87 ah, thanks! :) changed the answer in accordance to these news :)